# cmake dependency

Tags: gcc, compilation, cmake

I'm trying to create a cmake equivalent to the following make:

```
demo: main.cpp
   gcc -o demo main.cpp
   ./demo
```

demo is executed whenever demo is created.

This what I came to, but demo is not executed as I want:

```
add_executable(demo main.cpp)
add_custom_target(run_demo demo)
```

This is actually equivalent to:

```
all: demo
demo: main.cpp
   gcc -o demo main.cpp
run_demo:demo
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, as the Makefile snippets you posted do not do what you say they do. But judging by the comment on Kleist's answer, you want the demo to run each time it is compiled anew. You can achieve that as follows:

```
add_executable(demo main.cpp)
add_custom_command(TARGET demo
                   POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/demo)
```

Comment: this command is not robust for multiple config generator, prefer to use:
`POST_BUILD COMMAND demo` instead.  
 
> If COMMAND specifies an executable target name (created by the `add_executable()` command) it will automatically be replaced by the location of the executable created at build time.

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add run_demo to the ALL target:

```
add_custom_target(run_demo ALL demo)
```

Comment: This will execute demo each call to make, while this is not exactly what I want